# Sigma js graph doesn't render anything

Tags: javascript, canvas, sigma.js

The following code doesn't render anything , and it doesn't return any error :

```
var sigma = require('sigma');
var i,
    s,
    N = 100,
    E = 500,
    g = {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
    };

// Generate a random graph:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    g.nodes.push({
        id: 'n' + i,
        label: 'Node ' + i,
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        size: Math.random(),
        color: '#666'
    });

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
    g.edges.push({
        id: 'e' + i,
        source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
        target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
        size: Math.random(),
        color: '#ccc'
    });
sigma.renderers.def = sigma.renderers.canvas;
// Instantiate sigma:
s = new sigma({
    graph: g,
    container: document.getElementById('sigma-container')
});
```

Some notes: 
1.I already set the `max-width` and `height` :

```
#sigma-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

2.I'm running it on Node and so I have a separate js file and it gets compiled and passed to browser correctly.(at least I can see the code in chrome's developers tool)

3.I use the following html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sigma-container"></div>
      <script src="/javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

4.If instead of `getElementById('sigma-container')` I put the name of the div, it returns error : `Uncaught Container not found.`

Any idea on why it doesn't render ?

Answer (score 3):

The `container not found` error was fixed in this pull request https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/pull/653, but is not included in the latest release of sigma (v1.1.0). I manually built a copy off the master branch of the github project which included the fix, and resolved that issue.